# how to execute the sas scripts using java

Tags: java, unix, sas

I need to execute SAS scripts on regular basis either in sas EG (or) from Unix command prompt. Instead of manually executing these scripts I am thinking like execute the scripts automatically using java. I have tried something but unable to execute the SAS executable command. But I am performing some Unix commands through java.

Eg:

```
channelExec.setCommand("cd /xyz/abc.;ls"); (it will list out the files in the directory)

channelExec.setCommand("cd /xyz/abc.;sas  sas_program.sas");(unable to perform)
channelExec.connect();
```

Comment: Why would you want to introduce JAVA into the mix? If you can run them from the unix command line then just create a cron job to run them.

Comment: Actually I have some knowledge in java. I  need to maintain 100's of scripts, output file moving and automatic email triggering of script completions. That's why i preferred java

Comment: Everything you listed above are tasks for shell scripts. They have been used for decades for such tasks. It'll take you a few hours to learn and you'll then have that knowledge too. Also, should you hire another sys admin he'll feel right in working with right tools and you don't need to hire a Java coder.

Comment: These are SAS based reports. I am a fresher recently they have allocated this work for me. This is daily  routine job. So instead manually executing the jobs we can automatic these jobs. It will save my efforts and time. Please suggest me any alternative way to run the jobs automatically.

Comment: In Linux (and other Unices, probably) schedule the tasks using `crontab` (`man crontab` and `man 5 crontab`), To run a report 12:15 everyday you make a crontab entry: `15 12 * * * /pathto/sas reportname`

Comment: The report frequencies are weekly, monthly and quarterly so how can we handle these. And can we stop executing these jobs in some cases like  any DB failures (or) server failures. Please provide me some sample snippet code so it will helpful for me.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `cd` and `ls` commands are built in commands for the shell, so you do not need to worry about the search path for locating commands. But the `sas` is probably not being found because it is not in any of the directories listed in your path setting.  Either fix the path setting or add the full path to the `sas` command in your program.

Comment: I have tried with full path also but not worked.

Comment: Got error message like this "Error message: ksh: sas:  not found."